# Iterate over list of CompletableFutures in loop without recursion

Tags: java, recursion, completable-future

So I have this piece of Java code written with recursion.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<AllocationCandidateSet> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.range(0, 5000).forEach(__ -> candidates.add(new AllocationCandidateSet()));
        AllocationContext ctx = new AllocationContext();
        ctx.currentPlacementZoneAllocationCandidatesProvider = candidates.iterator();

        Main main = new Main();
        main.attemptAllocation(ctx).join();

        System.out.println(ctx.firstSuccessfulCandidateSet);
        System.out.println(ctx.iteration);
}

private CompletableFuture<AllocationContext> attemptAllocation(AllocationContext context) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(context)
            .thenCompose(this::getNextCandidateSet)
            .thenCompose(this::runAffinityFilters)
            .thenCompose(ctx -> {
                if (ctx.firstSuccessfulCandidateSet == null
                        && context.currentPlacementZoneAllocationCandidatesProvider.hasNext()) {
                    return attemptAllocation(ctx);
                } else {
                    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ctx);
                }
            });
}

private CompletableFuture<AllocationContext> getNextCandidateSet(AllocationContext ctx) {
    // For the sake of simplicity, I omitted most of the logic inside this method.
    ctx.currentCandidateSet = ctx.currentPlacementZoneAllocationCandidatesProvider.next();
    ctx.iteration++;
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ctx);
}

private CompletableFuture<AllocationContext> runAffinityFilters(AllocationContext ctx) {
    // This is a long running async operation doing DB calls
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ctx)
            .thenCompose(context -> {
                // Do some DB calls and run business logic and evaluate if the current AllocationCandidateSet is successful
                boolean success = context.iteration == 1876;
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(success);
            })
            .thenAccept(success -> {
                if (success) {
                    ctx.firstSuccessfulCandidateSet = ctx.currentCandidateSet;
                }
            })
            .thenApply(__ -> ctx);
}

public static class AllocationContext {
    Iterator<AllocationCandidateSet> currentPlacementZoneAllocationCandidatesProvider;
    AllocationCandidateSet currentCandidateSet;

    AllocationCandidateSet firstSuccessfulCandidateSet;

    int iteration = 0;
}

public static class AllocationCandidateSet {

}
```

}

Results are accumulated inside the AllocationContext which is a thread-safe object holder that contains Iterator - context.currentPlacementZoneAllocationCandidatesProvider.
The iterator is a normal one - having `next()` and `hasNext()` methods.

The `getNextCandidateSet()` method advances the iterator forward. This method is actually sync as opposed to async so theoretically `.thenCompose(this::getNextCandidateSet)` can be replaced with `.thenApply(this::getNextCandidateSet)` with little refactoring.

The problem I'm having is with the `runAffinityFilters()` method... This method is doing async calls to the Database with **must** be non-blocking. Its signature returns `CompletableFuture<AllocationContext>` and it's not feasible to change it.

Therefore, calls to `runAffinityFilters()` are chained in this CompletableFuture chain with recursion - after each runAffinityFilters() call, a check for successful result is made - if running the affinity filters yielded no success ( `(ctx.firstSuccessfulCandidateSet == null` ) and the iterator can be advanced ( `context.currentPlacementZoneAllocationCandidatesProvider.hasNext()` )
... then `allocateAttempt(ctx)` is invoked again.

Is there a way to replace the recursion with regular iteration? With the recursive solution I'm hitting StackOverflowError near the 1000th loop...
It would be ideal to continue running `runAffinityFilters()` as async call, waiting for it to complete, checking the condition `if (ctx.firstSuccessfulCandidateSet == null && context.currentPlacementZoneAllocationCandidatesProvider.hasNext())`  and then continuing with next iteration.

Comment: If `runAffinityFilters()` returns `CompletableFuture<Void>`, then `ctx` is of type `Void`, so this code would not compile. Could you provide a [mre]? (side note, `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(context).thenCompose(this::getNextCandidateSet)` is a complicated way to do `getNextCandidateSet(context)`)

Comment: I updated the question with a full working although very simplified and stripped example

Comment: Good, however there is nothing asynchronous in the code you posted, so everything is effectively running recursively on the main thread, and `CompletableFuture` is useless. If I make `runAffinityFilters()` use `thenComposeAsync()` instead of `thenCompose()`, it succeeds.

Comment: Well, obviously my 'real' implementation of runAffinityFilters() is not simply returning CompletableFuture.completedFuture(success)... I pasted the code like that for simplicity - as I said, it's doing DB calls in reality. You don't expect me to write down a working example with a DB stack, do you?

Comment: I indeed don’t expect a DB call (it wouldn’t be a minimal example), I expect something that properly represents it. Here it’s not the case, so it does not really help understanding your problem. If your DB call was truly async, you wouldn’t have an issue, as indicated in my previous comment.

Comment: I see... I didn't know that I can force the execution of runAffinityFilters() to be on a different thread by using thenComposeAsync(). That's very usable and exactly what I need!
Thank you!

The thing with runAffinityFilters() is that it may be sync or async - depending on conditions. I guess in my lab env it was mostly doing sync calls and hence the StackOverflowError